# Why is ASP.NET 4.6 not serving me pages over HTTP/2?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, http2

I have created an ASP.NET 4.6 MVC application right out of the box from Visual Studio 2015, I have set `SSL = true` in the project settings, however when I debug the web application in IIS Express, the pages are not being served up over HTTP/2

[image]

In Scott's [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/released-today-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-4-6-asp-net-5-ef-7-previews), it showed the pages served up over HTTP/2

[image]

I'm on Windows 10 RTM + VS2015 RTM.

Are there some other settings that I've missed?

Comment: Is HTTP/2 being negotiated by TLS extensions? Or is the client sending an upgrade header to HTTP/2?

Comment: I see your localhost was https, but "Note – Currently, HTTP2 works only on SSL. So I opened the same page first using HTTP which used HTTP1.1 and then used https: which used HTTP2 protocol (which is shown here as h2)" (http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/brijmishra/archive/2015/12/01/leveraging-http-2-with-asp-net-4-6-and-iis10.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET 5.2.7 in Visual Studio Community 2019 I changed the web settings so that the web application is served from a `https` url. This single change made the content being served over HTTP2 in IIS Express as can be seen in the screenshots below.

[image: Web project settings]
[image: Browser inspector results]